# How to implement and run Leetcode Problems (LinkedList, Trees) locally from scratch in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list, local, implementation

I want to implement Leetcode problems on my local machine as I am a beginner and I want to master programming in python. I think implementing the problems locally helps me understand the problem in detail. So here's what Leetcode's starting point looks like for [206. Reverse a Linked List](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/).

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    ## your code goes here...
```

There're plenty of YT videos explaining the algorithm and how to solve it **WITHIN** leetcode's platform, but none of them teaches how to implement it from scratch.

So, I have tried to do the following:

```
##
from typing import List

class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, head = None, next = None):
        self.head = head
        self.next = next
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.head

## 
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = ListNode()
        
    def reverseList(self, nums: ListNode)-> ListNode:
        prev, cur = None, self.head
        
        while cur:
            temp = cur.next
            cur.next = prev
            prev = cur
            cur = temp
        return prev
```

The solution itself is correct when I submit it in leetcode. But when I implement my own main as the following, I get the following.

```
## main1
if __name__ =="__main__":
    nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
    sol = Solution()
    ans = sol.reverseList(nums)
    print(ans)
```

The output looks like this:
`<__main__.ListNode object at 0x000002E6E5CFB940>`

**Can you please help me with how to properly implement the main locally and view the object datatypes?** I face this issue for trees and list-node type of problems.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you please share what the expected output is? Your output is not an error, but I supposed you want to write a function which will display the linked list.

Comment: The expected output is: 
Output: [5,4,3,2,1]. Yes, I want to display my output

Comment: The `__repr__` function in ListNode defines how an object is represented as a string. I believe you'll have to write a recursive function to iterate through your ListNode object and store the values in a python list to print it.